# Adding a custom region to a HTML5_base theme (Drupal)

Tags: php, drupal-6, themes

I'm new to creating custom themes. I'm trying to add a custom region. The custom region I'm trying to create is called "Top Bars."
in the **.info file**:

```
regions[header] = Header
regions[content_top] = Content top
regions[content_bottom] = Content bottom
regions[sidebar_first] = First sidebar
regions[sidebar_second] = Second sidebar
regions[footer_region] = Footer
regions[top_bars] = Top Bars
```

in the **page.tpl.php** file:

```
<?php if ($top_bars): ?>

<?php print $top_bars ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I also have the Devel module enabled and tried clearing my cache.

I also tried writing this in the **page.tpl.php** file:

```
<div id="top_bars">
        <?php print $top_bars ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog [post](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/1188/how-to-create-custom-regions-in-node-tpl-php-in-drupal-6) :

basicly the guy had to add this to his **template.php** :

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['cool_node_region'] = theme('blocks', 'cool_node_region');
}
```

Comment: not sure what i'm missing. i decided to change the names that i was using and just follow the blog post word for word. I put the theme_preprocess_node function inside the template.php file and I created a cool-node-region class in my css file.

Comment: still the same problem? try a different theme/engine maybe and see if it's a bug in drupal or just the theme engine.